# Where is the operator "<" used in this sample?

Tags: c++, stl

I tried STL sample program using "map".

http://ideone.com/LB8xvh

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class ItemName
{
    char name[80];
public:
    ItemName(char *s) { strcpy(name, s); }
    char *get() { return name; }
};

bool operator<(ItemName a, ItemName b)
{
    return strcmp(a.get(), b.get()) < 0;
}

class ItemObj
{
    char str[80];
public:
    ItemObj(char *s) { strcpy(str, s); }
    char *get() { return str; }
};

char itemdata[][80] = {
    "potion", "heal HP",
    "key", "unlock a door",
    "lamp", "light",
};


int main() {
    map<ItemName, ItemObj> items;

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        items.insert(
                pair<ItemName, ItemObj>(
                    ItemName(itemdata[i*2]),
                    ItemObj(itemdata[i*2+1]))); // ***** pair *****

    }

    map<ItemName, ItemObj>::iterator p;

    char str[80];
    const int kMaxLoop = 5;
    int nLoop = 0;
    while(nLoop < kMaxLoop) {
        cout << "> ";
        cin >> str;
        p = items.find(str);
        if(p != items.end() ) {
            cout << p->second.get() << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "unknown item." << endl;
        }
        nLoop++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, I am not quite sure where the operator "<" is used.
If I comment out the definition of the operator "<", I receive lots of errors.

Comment: Make it easy on yourself and use `std::string`. C strings are just extra work for no benefit here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map` has a parameter to specify how to compare elements in the map (needed because a map always maintains its contents sorted in order by key). By default, that's `std::less<T>`.

`std::less<T>`, in turn, will do the comparison using `operator<`.

You *can* create a map of items for which `operator<` isn't defined, but to do it you need to specify the comparison function/functor explicitly.

That said: your `ItemData` and `ItemObj` are both really just doing things that `std::string` can already do. You could reduce most of the code above to something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> items{
    { "potion", "heal HP"       },
    { "key", "unlock a door"    },
    { "lamp", "light"           }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Jerry Coffin. I could understand well about how it works. Also, I appreciate that you show me the alternative way using the std::string.

Answer (score 5):

It is used internally by the `map` to place and find entries. Otherwise, `find` would have to compare the key you supply it against literally every single other entry one by one and you couldn't iterate the map in key order.

Basically, `map`s efficiently store elements in order. To do that, they have to have some way to know what the order *is*, and they do that by calling `operator<` (unless you specify otherwise).

Comment: That's not quite correct. [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)'s third template parameter which by default is `std::less<Key>` uses `operator<`, hence you could create a `std::map` which does *not* require `operator<`.

Comment: Thank you very much, David Schwartz and Daniel Frey. I see that the map uses the operator "<" internally. Also, I will study about std::less<Key>.